# Downloading Image as data into iOS from SQL

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimage

Good day,

I need my app to download an image from a SQL database and save it to Core Data.

The strange thing is that I get the image but when I assign it as `Data` then it crashes if I force it or returns as `nil` when I don’t force it.

I have tried few things but they all crash.

The code that I have start with is as  follows:

```
if let returnedData = data {
    let returnedString = String(data: returnedData, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
    
    print("<JON>Returned Data: \(returnedString!)")
                    
    var jsonResult = NSArray()
                    
    do {
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: returnedData, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray
    }catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
                    
    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    var iData: Data?
    for i in jsonResult {
        jsonElement = i as! [String:Any] as NSDictionary
        for (v, k) in jsonElement {
            print("<JON> vk ",v, k)
            if v as! String == "image" {
                print("<JON> img:")
                iData = (k as? Data)
            }
        }
                        
        let id = jsonElement["id"] as! String
        let imgData = jsonElement["image"]! as? Data
        print("<JON-End>", id, imgData, iData)
}
```

The Output from this is

```
<JON>Returned Data: [{"id":"E5F61103-38B7-4DCC-BA76-542AFB6A7AB0","image":"Optional(71918 bytes)"}]
<JON> vk  id E5F61103-38B7-4DCC-BA76-542AFB6A7AB0
<JON> vk  image Optional(71918 bytes)
<JON> img:
<JON-End> E5F61103-38B7-4DCC-BA76-542AFB6A7AB0 nil nil
```

Any idea on what I am missing?

Reagrds,
Jonas

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. Your returned data is not what you think it is. Notably the value associated with the `image` key is a 21 character string, `"Optional(71918 bytes)"`, i.e. the character `O`, followed by `p`, followed by `t`, etc. The value is that short string, not the 71kb image asset.

   So whatever is preparing this JSON is not including the image, but rather this short string. (As an aside, that string looks suspiciously like a string representation that Swift would generate from an optional, so I wonder if the image was uploaded incorrectly.)

   You haven’t shared how this JSON was prepared, so we can’t comment on that further. But I’d suggest confirming what is really in the SQL database and figure out whether the SQL database contains that string (suggesting a problem with your original upload routine) or whether the SQL database contains the image and the problem rests in how the response was created.
2. [`JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) only handles values that are `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSNull`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSArray`. And your example has a string that is `"Optional(71918 bytes)"`. You can’t just take that `NSString` and cast it to a `Data`. That will always fail.
3. You can’t just include binary data of an image payload within JSON. There are two options here:

   - You could have your server base-64 encode the image payload before adding it to the JSON (making what is transmitted 33% larger than the actual image asset) and then the app could base-64 decode it after parsing it from the JSON.

     Using `Decodable` and `JSONDecoder` you can may be able to parse this base-64 string to a `Data` automatically, but if using `JSONSerialization` you’ll have to do that manually.
   - Rather than including the image in the JSON, provide a URL by which the client could download the image alone.

   But JSON is a text representation and images are binary assets.

Comment: Thanks, I will change my approach and use an url for the image.